# Faster DatagramChannel write

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, datagram

I'm building a high performance network application that needs to pump out hundreds of megabits per second. It is UDP based and I'm using a DatagramChannel to send the data.

My application is separated into two parts, with one thread doing each part. One part is reading from something, doing some processing and putting the result in a queue to be sent. The second part is reading from the queue and writing to the DatagramChannel.

The thread doing the writing is falling behind greatly (sometimes causing out of memory errors due to how much data is in the queue) and I'm wondering if there are ways to speed up the DatagramChannel write operation.

Comment: No. Get rid of the queue and the writing thread and have the reading thread do the sends as well. That way it cannot possibly get ahead. Or else use non-blocking me so you can be aware when writes aren't working ...but then all you're going to do is either lose the writes or slow down the reads.

Comment: I don't have issues fixing the "getting ahead" part, but thanks for the suggestion. I was considering porting it to C-sockets. I'm fairly certain that I will get a bit better performance from that.

Comment: How fast is the data going out over the DatagramChannel and what is your NIC capable of?

Comment: I'm able to get around 150 Mbps and my NIC is capable of around 200. For the record, the performance is better when using 2 threads, even when one is falling behind.